# Is there any javascript construction block script/library alike Appinventor or Scratch?

Tags: javascript, math, formula, app-inventor

I was wondering if there is any javascript script or library that i could install on my site that would work much alike Appinventor or Scratch design blocks.
I am trying to create a small formula creator from blocks, so i don't need something too complicated. Need just basic math functions.

Not to be confused, I am not looking for either other math formula creators like Latex, nor to similar sites like Appinventor or Scratch.
Just a visual design block alike script.

Thank you.

Comment: Questions asking for a 3rd party library or tool are considered off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Sorry didn't knew it was off-topic as I've seen other topics asking for this kind of things. However I just asked if there are any scripts so I think it should be a valid one as the answer could have been yes or no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the library used by App Inventor is available. 
It is called [Blockly](https://developers.google.com/blockly/).